# Photoshop GIF reverse

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, animated-gif, adobe-creative-cloud, timeline

I've got a question about the Photoshop Timeline. I imported this [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EF3Fu.gif) (you will have to refresh the page, to see the animation),selected all frames and reversed them, but now, after i exported the GIF, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PY9l.gif)...
As you can see, at the beginning of the animation, it doesn't remove the older layers, altough they are deactivated then. 
Does anyone has an idea what the problem could be, or an solution for it, because I tried everything I could and it still doesn't work.
Thanks for any answer!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you did not delete the frames that show the upper part of the envelope. This can be done by selecting these frames and choosing Delete Frames from the Timeline menu. Also, if you want that the gif stops after playing, save it using File > Save for Web or File > Export > Save for Web (depends on Photoshop version) and in Animation > Looping Options select Once.

Comment: I am sure this answer had an image. Where did it go?